# Prevent numbers from being pasted in textbox in .net windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have prevented numbers from being typed in text box using key down event. But when using Ctrl+V or pasting content through mouse, the numbers are being entered in the text box. How to prevent this? I have to allow all text to be pasted/typed except numbers.

Comment: What is the expected result from pasting `"one 2 three"` into the text box?

Comment: In this case, the system should display alert message the 'text entered is invalid'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On quite simple approach would be to check the text using the `TextChanged` event. If the text is valid, store a copy of it in a string variable. If it is not valid, show a message and then restore the text from the variable:

```
string _latestValidText = string.Empty;
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox target = sender as TextBox;
    if (ContainsNumber(target.Text))
    {
        // display alert and reset text
        MessageBox.Show("The text may not contain any numbers.");
        target.Text = _latestValidText;
    }
    else
    {
        _latestValidText = target.Text;
    }
}
private static bool ContainsNumber(string input)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\d+");
}
```

This will handle any occurrence of numbers in the text, regardless of where or how many times they may appear.

Comment: This isn't an ideal solution.  Because `TextChanged` is asynchronous, you're not actually *cancelling* the pasting of the text, merely restoring the old text quickly.  There may be a flickering of the pasted text that was invalid before the old text is restored.

Answer (score 3):

use the TextBox.TextChanged event. Then use the same code as you have in the KeyDown event. In fact, you no longer need the keydown event

Comment: I have used KeyEventArgs of key down event and using e.KeyCode, I have prevented numbers! But while using text changed event i can't get key code for a key!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the JavaScript change event (onchange) instead of the keydown event. It'll check only when the user leaves the textbox though.

Comment: Using Javascript events is *really* hard in winforms applications ;)

Comment: Yes... This is windows forms!