# How Do I Prevent Paste Alpha bates on a text box Windows

Tags: c#

I m Developing A windows Application i m easily handle to enter the only numbers in Text box using key press event. but i still able to paste alpha bates in text boxes how can i restrict to paste alpha bates in text box

Comment: Basically the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757913/prevent-numbers-from-being-pasted-in-textbox-in-net-windows-forms?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

us the use the TextChanged event.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var rgx = new Regex(@"\D");
            textBox1.Text = rgx.Replace(textBox1.Text, "");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use KeyPress event,

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't explicitly state what UI technology you're using, but if it's WinForms you could try using a MaskedTextBox with the appropriate mask property setting.

[MSDN MaskedTextBox Mask Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx)